# Plugin architecture via service alternatives

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, android-service

I was searching for a way to implement a plugin-based Android application and found [this great article](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/06/plugins.html), describing a service-based approach to plugins.

My goals in attempting this service-based plugin architecture were:

1. Avoid static linking of an additional module ("plugin") to the core app.
2. Avoid distributing the source code of the core app or library.
3. Optionally pass the core app/library through Proguard, protecting key parts.

The service-based approach meets goal #1 very well, but when it comes to goals #2 and #3, I find myself in an infinite loop (i.e. "chasing my tail"):

The service-based plugin demo implemented in the article works great because... it only returns **built-in types** (see `IBinaryOp.aidl`).

But in my *real-world* application, I need to return my own classes, some of which are complex and include "trade secrets".

Is this a chicken & egg kind of situation in which, no matter what I do, I will always have to expose some of my core classes?

Or is this problem solvable?

One of the ways I am considering to address this (workaround really?) is by using **interfaces** for my classes-to-be-returned-via-the-service and so:

1. The plugin (written by others) still needs to know about my namespace and therefore will need my Library Project's JAR at **build time**, but it won't have any access to the implementation source code.
2. I may be able to divide my current monolithic Library Project into 2 JARs: One containing the interfaces only, and the other not even released as a JAR but rather part of my application's APK.

Am I thinking in the right direction? Or do you spot some misconceptions?

Are there better ways to approach this problem?

Are there demo projects out there that have already addressed this challenge (i.e. all 3 goals outlined above) successfully and can be used as a reference or tutorial?

Answer (score 5):

> Are there better ways to approach this problem?

You have to ship the AIDL in source form. That *is* an interface. You do not have to then separately have *another* layer of interfaces. The *implementation* of the Java classes referenced in the AIDL can be in a JAR.

That being said, wild horses couldn't get me to do what you're doing, due to version management.

Unless you plan on holding your third parties at gunpoint, you cannot force them to upgrade their editions of your JAR. Hence, you either:

- Can never change those classes, or
- Have to *very carefully* manage versioning, such as having separate IPC endpoints per version, so that your core code can handle arbitrary versions of third-party code with arbitrary versions of your JAR

> Are there demo projects out there that have already addressed this challenge (i.e. all 3 goals outlined above) successfully and can be used as a reference or tutorial?

Your goals can be met by any of Android's IPC mechanisms:

- Bound service using custom classes, as you are proposing
- Bound service using only stock classes, like `String` and `List` and `Bundle`
- Command pattern with services (i.e., sending commands via `startService()`)
- Broadcast `Intents`
- `ContentProviders`
- Activities

The crux of your difficulty lies in this assumption:

> I need to return my own classes

I would completely flip that around, to: you should stick with standard Android classes for the actual IPC, ones that you and the third-party code will both recognize and be able to work with.

This still has version management that you need to do, but it's down to more conventional "sanitize your inputs" logic, the way you would do with any Web service or other exposed API. And if you want to ship some "helper" code, in source or a JAR, to make consuming your API easier, that's cool, because you are no longer dependent upon the specific version of those classes in the JAR.

In terms of "demo projects", that would completely depend upon what sort of API you are trying to create.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will be studying it for a while before deciding on the optimal approach in my case. Returning only stock classes will require re-designing and re-writing a significant part of my library. And thanks for the tips regarding versioning, you definitely got me thinking...